# wierd json error in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have following json:

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 1
    },
    "spellcheck": {
        "suggestions": [
            "a",
            {
                "numFound": 4,
                "startOffset": 0,
                "endOffset": 1,
                "suggestion": [
                    "api",
                    "and",
                    "as",
                    "an"
                ]
            },
            "collation",
            "api"
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to access the 'suggestion' array and for that I am using this in jQuery:

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:8983/solr/suggest/?q=' + query + '&wt=json&json.wrf=?', {

})
    .done(function(response){
        // just for testing
        alert(response.spellcheck.suggestions.suggestion); // error: response.spellcheck is not defined
    });
```

The value of 'response.spellcheck' is shown undefined whereas 'response.responseHeader' shows [object Object] and also I can access elements under responseHeader. But I cannot figure out what's the issue with 'spellcheck'. Help!

Comment: Have you tried logging the entirety of response, to see if you're actually getting what you think you're getting?

Comment: Hmm. I tried it. In response I am not getting any 'spellcheck', only 'responseHeader'. Why!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use console.log for printing the response then you can do accordingly

Comment: May look funny, but doing this helped me to know about the cause of the problem :D ..! So, this answer deserves it.

Answer (score 5):

`suggestions.suggestions` can't work. `suggestions` is an array. You need to index the array with the `[]` operator to get to a specific suggestion.

Specifically, based on the JSON you posted, you want `suggestions[1].suggestion`.

Comment: I can't even access 'spellcheck', accessing suggestions/suggestion is the later thing.

Comment: Let's say if I use 'response.spellcheck.suggestions', it shows me 'undefined'

Comment: Something is up with your response then, copying and pasting your exact JSON to a fiddle and logging it works: http://jsfiddle.net/spDTP/1/ (with @meagar's answer)

Comment: Also 'response.spellcheck.suggestions[0]' also shows 'undefined'. Meaning there is something wrong with 'spellcheck'..!!

Comment: Check your spelling also - the JSON contains `suggestions` and you have `suggesstions` in your original question.

Comment: Stop spamming comments and *debug your code*. You've got Chrome's developer tools or Firebug, sotType `response`. See what it contains. Check each of the sub-objects, and see what *they* contain. This is extremely trivial debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The correct spelling is `response.spellcheck.suggestions` (you have used `suggesstions`) and this is an array, so you can look at its context using the index... for example:

```
alert(response.spellcheck.suggestions.suggestion[0]); // "a"
```

So you need:

```
response.spellcheck.suggestions.suggestion[1].suggestion
```

[Example on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2F9Vq/).

Comment: Okay - but accessing the data as shown above does get you the data right - you've seen the JS Fiddle?

Comment: Problem is with getting the proper response from Solr, the JSON I have written in ques is fetched by writing the url in address bar. But using console.log I found that response doesnot contain 'spellcheck', it contains only 'responseHeaders'